# PHP name validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have been creating some validation for a signup form, and I have come across an error when validating the user's name.

I have used an input of "Test" for both firstname and lastname and I still get an error when it should allow the input, since 
`!preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)` should allow both lower and uppercase characters?

Also the error that I get seems to be only triggering for the firstname and not last name.

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require_once 'config.php';

        $errors = [];

        foreach($_POST as $field => $value){
            if($field === 'firstname' || $field === 'lastname' && !preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)){
                $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters please try again.";
                echo $error;
            }         
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: post your html please

Comment: it's the condition logic which is wrong. put () around the or-clause

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets around your "OR" condition. The "AND" takes precedence over "OR".

```
if(($field === 'firstname' || $field === 'lastname') && !preg_match('/^[a-z]*$/i', $value)){
     $errors[] = "{$field} has invalid characters please try again.";
}
```

NB: In your code above, you have an *"undefined variable"* : `$error`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that:

1. you make your conditional more direct/brief/DRY with: `in_array($key,['firstname','lastname'])` instead of two separate checks.
2. you avoid the unnecessary use of a regex function when there is a non-regex function that was designed to perform the same task: `!ctype_alpha($value)`

This is what the implementation could look like:([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JBYO2))

```
$_POST=['submit'=>'','firstname'=>'legit','lastname'=>'n0tl3g!t'];

$errors=[];
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key,['firstname','lastname']) && !ctype_alpha($value)){
        $errors[]="$key field contains invalid value: $value";
    }
}
var_export($errors);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'lastname field contains invalid value: n0tl3g!t',
)
```

---

As for improving the UX of your application, I recommend using HTML5 validation in your form to prevent the submission of invalid field values like so...

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="letters only">
```